# how i get to know which master page my site is using SP 2010

Tags: 2010, master-page, custom-masterpage

In sharePoint 2010 site, if i go to _/catalogs/masterpages, i can see many master pages. But how i know which master page my site is using?

The name of master page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit this URL and it will show you which MP is set:

```
http://<siteURL>/_layouts/changesitemasterpage.aspx
```